# Learning networking fundamentals

Tags: computer-science, networking

Not having a CS degree has left large holes in my programming related knowledge.
In particular I'd really like to learn some of the computer networking stuff I would have got in a good CS degree.
The problem I really have is "not knowing what I don't know". 
So far I know I don't know anything about the following (as far as computer networks are concearned)

-sockets

-ports

-internet protocol (the whole IP stack I keep hearing about).

Can anyone add more to the list?
Can anyone suggest a project (writing a toy web server?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have a CS degree, and I don't know anything about those things. They were 400 level electives (at UIUC), and I opted to take different ones. I now realize my choice was poor and impractical. Networking would have been wiser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend reading TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 1, by Stevens.  It's surprisingly easy to read and by the end of it you will 1) have learned a lot and 2) have a much better idea of what you still don't know. :-)

As for good projects, I suggest making a toy web client first.  Just write something that will download a webpage and save it to a file (like wget or curl).  A toy web server is a good second project.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll check it out, I like your ideas for projects too. Ta!

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but could you recommend something written in the last 5 to 10 years? This book is from 1993, which makes me think there's a whole lot left out of that the modern era uses.

Comment: @NoniA. There's a second edition of the book (updated by Kevin Fall), released in 2014.  ISBN 9332535957.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good point and to know more is usually pretty beneficial. But I would say in depth knowledge of network systems is really necessary only for specific class of programming problems. Majority of programming projects don't require such profound knowledge. Is essence programmers and network experts (IT Professionals as Microsoft likes to call them) are two different occupations (except for that few cases) and they even require, I would say, two different mindsets.

Comment: IT Professionals need to know a lot about configuring networks (routers, servers, etc.), but the original poster is asking about network programming.  Network programming is a pretty useful skill in a programmer's toolbox, IMO.  Obviously, it depends on what kinds of applications you plan to write.